# Installation for OpenCPU

Tags: r, installation, opencpu

I was following the OpenCPU manual for installing their server (https://opencpu.github.io/server-manual/opencpu-server.pdf, sec 2.2) and everything was installing fine and at the last step I got this message:

> Adding opencpu user account usermod: no changes Creating log files...
>   Taking ownership of system directories... Making scripts executable...
>   Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork: Considering conflict
>   mpm_worker for mpm_prefork: Module mpm_prefork already enabled
>   Enabling opencpu in apache... Reloading apparmor... Restarting
>   apache... Installation done! **Failed to execute operation: No such file
>   or directory** Setting up libprotobuf-dev:amd64 (2.6.1-1.3) ...
>   Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...

I have bolded the part I am worried about, did the installation succeed? how can I fix this problem ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If everything works you can probably ignore this. The installer is cleaning up some stuff at the end, but it's being a bit overly verbose when trying to wipe a directory that was already gone.

Comment: Thanks. Also, as I said I followed the manual on installing R packages on the server, however in: ipaddress/ocpu/user/janeDoe/library......it says on the webpage "R package library for user data not found." Why is this? how can I fix it to write R web apps?

Comment: Does `janeDoe` have a home R package library ? If you are root, packages just get installed to `/ocpu/library/`

Comment: I installed packages using "sudo i R" in (~) directory. So you are saying to do that in the (/janeDoe) directory?   how can i make janeDoe have a home R package?

Comment: If you start R as regular user without sudo, it will automatically install packages at the appropriate location in your home dir.